# Explicit differential equation of the global character of UIR's of SL(2,R)?

Tags: representation-theory, semisimple-lie-algebras

The semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}:=sl(2,\mathbb{R})$ has the Casimir operator
$$\Omega:=(1/2)h^2+ef+fe$$
with respect to the standard basis $(h,e,f)$. For an irreducible unitary representation $\pi$ of $G:=SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ the global character $\Theta_\pi$ satisfies the differential equation
$$\Omega.\Theta_\pi=\chi(\Omega) \cdot \Theta_\pi$$
when $\Omega \in Z(U\mathfrak{g})$ is considered a left-invariant fundamental vector field on $G$. On the regular points of $G$ the distribution $\Theta_\pi$ is given by an analytic function, see the explicit form in "Knapp: Representation Theory of Semisimple Groups, Prop. 10.14".

My question:

- Which explicit form has the differential equation above for the
  analytic function $\Theta_\pi$?
- Which differential operators in explicit form define $\Omega$ on the two Cartan
  subgroups and their conjugates?